# Evaluating the contour integral: $\oint_C \frac{\sin 2z}{(6z-\pi)^3}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I am trying to evaluate the following integral, but don't know how to take the coefficient of $z$ out of the parenthesis to get it into the Cauchy integral form. Any help is appreciated.

$$ \oint_C \frac{\sin 2z}{(6z-\pi)^3}dz$$

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean as in 
$$6^3\left(z-\frac{\pi}{6}\right)^3?$$

Comment: Hmm. I tried expanding it out and got into a mess, and didn't realize it was that simple. Thanks.